# Trying to Include Contractions Using Regexp Parsing in Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I've been parsing words using a word cloud generator in python. The generator was written in python 2, but I'm running in Anaconda. Some texts run through the generator throw up "don" instead of "don't", and also common contraction endings like "ll" or "re." Rather than just push those into a stop word file, I'd like to include words like "don't" if they appear with significant frequency in the text. The code already in place is this:

```
regexp = self.regexp if self.regexp is not None else r"\w[\w']+"
```

Thinking to include apostraphes, I attempted to replace it with this:

```
regexp = self.regexp if self.regexp is not None else r"(?u)\b\w[a-zA-Z0-9_']+\b"
```

The test text I'm running through is Project Gutenberg's *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*, with all of their project associated text and licensing stripped away. Contractions are still appearing broken in the output file with "don" and "ll" among most common words. I checked the text file using find and didn't see any broken words as the source of the error. I had a similar result using Moby Dick as well.

Any suggestions?

Here is a sample that produces "ll" and "wouldn" as words when run with the "r"\w[\w']+"" in regexp:

```
    ‘Well!’ thought Alice to herself, ‘after such a fall as this, I shall
    think nothing of tumbling down stairs! How brave they’ll all think me at
    home! Why, I wouldn’t say anything about it, even if I fell off the top
    of the house!’ (Which was very likely true.)

    Down, down, down. There was nothing else to do, so Alice soon began
    talking again. ‘Dinah’ll miss me very much to-night, I should think!’
```

Thanks to Matteo below, the solution I used is:

`regexp = self.regexp if self.regexp is not None else r"(?u)\b\w[a-zA-Z0-9_'’]+\b"`

Comment: Please post a sample of the file as well:)

Comment: Can you please include a [mcve] of the problem? The entire text of Alice's Adventures in Wonderland is *not* **minimal** ;)

Comment: Can you provide a **minimal** sample of **the input file** the reproduces the problem? I'm not going to download Alice in Wonderland, to try to debug it! Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47606877/edit) to include a sample input that generates that result.

Comment: @EdMyers Yes, I know; exactly. Which is why it's unreasonable to expect someone else to figure this out! :D

Comment: @TomLord Took me a few minutes to put up a minimal sample. I may not be as fast as you younger people, but I am not unreasonable. just tell me what you need and be patient. 8D

Comment: @csharpcoder Sorry, but it took me a few to respond since I was trying to answer someone else. Please come back if you don't mind and have a look.

Comment: In your regex you are looking for a straight apostrophe (`'`, U+0027), but the original text uses `’` (U+2019, a "right single quotation mark").

Comment: @MatteoItalia Aha! Thank you. How do I upvote you?

Comment: Eh, that's a comment, so you can upvote it with the triangle that comes up when hovering on its left, but if this actually solved your problem I'll move it to a proper answer.

Comment: @EdMyers: ok, moved to an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your regex you are looking for a straight apostrophe (`'`, U+0027), but the original text uses `’` (U+2019, a "right single quotation mark"). You'll have to adjust your regexes accordingly.

By the way, given that now you start having to match "complex" Unicode characters (in particular, one that doesn't fit in a single byte in UTF-8) you probably want to make sure that you are using proper unicode strings around (`unicode` in Python 2, `str` in Python 3) to avoid surprises.